# Forcing application on Heroku to use https

Tags: nginx, ssl, heroku, https, next.js

My application currently supports both http and https and I would like to force the use of the latter when someone tries to access the first one (which also happens to be the default). However, I am a bit unsure of how to set this up when it comes to how I've deployed things.

To give a higher-level perspective, I have **3 nodes** running on Heroku corresponding to:

- A Next.js frontend app
- An Express backend server
- An nginx reverse proxy that acts as the entrypoint of the system and redirects requests to either the front or the backend.

How would one go about forcing the use of https? Is that configured at the proxy level? at the frontend level? Or maybe at the dns config level?

I think that's usually done at the proxy level but I'm not sure, plus the fact that I'm using the ssl certificate that heroku provides out the box, makes things even more confusing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: yes normally thats a proxy use case to terminate the TLS connection. Can you share your current NGINX configuration? Do you have access the to TLS cert and key in your proxy node?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My nginx config only consists of 2 simple redirects for / and /api to the domain names assigned by default by heroku. There is currently no ssl related config in there since that is currently provided by heroku.

Comment: what do you mean by redirect? are you talking about proxieng? Please share your nginx config.

Comment: Sure. Here it is https://pastebin.com/gtzuCLKH

Comment: For what it's worth, I ended up resolving it by hosting the proxy on digital ocean and using  letsencrypt/certbot for the ssl certificate.

Comment: Okay ... so as long as it is working. :) But yes your setup is the right approach. Proxy for TLS terminitation with let's encrypt.